# Templates cannot be virtual error when templating class

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have such abstract class:

```
template<class V, class K>
class MyAbstractCache {
protected:
    ...
public:
    ...
    virtual size_t getSize() const = 0;
    ...
};
```

Then a derived one:

```
template<class V, class K>
class MyLRUCache : public MyAbstractCache<V, K> {
    ...
public:
    ...
    virtual size_t getSize() const {
        return _key_to_value.size();
    }
```

The problem is when I put implementation of `getSize()` out of class declaration I get the compiler error: templates may not be ‘virtual’.

```
template<class V, class K>
virtual size_t MyLRUCache<V, K>::getSize() { ... } // compile error :(
```

Is there a way to deal with it?

Comment: The `virtual` keyword is only for declarations, not definitions (implementations). Besides, you only need the `virtual` keyword in the declaration of the function in the base class, not in the child class.

Comment: Someone should file a diagnostic bug with GCC. That error message is atrocious.

Comment: Note that this would also be an error with a class. It really has nothing to do with templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`virtual` can only be used inside the class definition, so just remove it for outside-class member function definition.

```
template<class V, class K>
size_t MyLRUCache<V, K>::getSize() const { ... }
```

Note you should add `const` too since it's a const member function.